# Not able to see 'Lifecycle management' option for ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have created ADLS (Azure Data Lake Storage) Gen2 resource (StorageV2 with hierarchical name space enabled). The region I created the resource in is Central US and the performance/access tier is Standard/Hot and replication is LRS. But for this resource I can't see 'Lifecycle management' option on the portal. ADLS Gen2 is simply a StorageV2 account with hierarchical namespace enabled, and since the lifecycle management option exists for StorageV2 as per Microsoft documentation , it should be available. My requirement is to use this storage for big data analytics (HDInsight) and get rid of old files after certain number of days. If this is some known limitation of ADLS Gen2, is there any workaround to have files older than certain number of days automatically deleted?

**Update(Screenshot)**

[image]

Comment: Go to storage account under the `Data Lake Storage`, there should be Lifecycle management.

Comment: no there isn't , check the screenshot. It's mostly a bug I think.

Comment: @Dhiraj, first, you should contact ms support for the UI issue. As a workaround, if you know programming, you can write your own code for your purpose.

Comment: @IvanYang yes, I have done it now -- at the time of posting this question I thought that maybe for the combination of storage + region, lifecycle is not probably supported so I wanted to confirm that by asking question. But turns out to be a bug.

Comment: @Dhiraj just FYI, it can work at my side as per your step.

Comment: it's a bug based on what I learnt from the support

Comment: @Dhiraj, ok, got that. Do you mind post an answer for tracking / explain the issue?

Comment: @IvanYang I will post once I have an update -- but as of now it is pretty inconsistent, certain users are able to see the option, certain aren't.

Comment: @IvanYang it's confirmed to be a bug.

Comment: @Dhiraj, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** This is confirmed as a bug and engineering team is currently working on the fix.

What kind of subscription are you using?

I have noticed, lifecycle management option is not available for Azure Free trial Subscription:

[image]

"Lifecycle Management" is supported by the multi-protocol access on Data Lake Storage preview.

[image]

I'm able to see lifecycle management option from our end.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not a free trial subscription , it's an organizational subscription -- the support already confirmed that it's inconsistent, certain users can see this option, certain users cant.

Comment: it's confirmed to be a bug!

Comment: Hi @Dhiraj, I have updated the answer will the latest information on this issue.