# Change access tier recursively

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account and the vast majority of the files are just for archiving, so I would like to changes their access tier to Archive to reduce cost. Is there any way/tool to recursively change access tier for a folder or do I have to write e.g. an application that recursively changes the access tier for the archive folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [storage-lifecycle-management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal) for ADLS Gen2.

It's easy to configure and automatically move blobs to archive tier.

Steps as below:

1.Nav to azure portal -> Lifecycle Management -> then click "Add rule":

[image]

2.In the new page, check "Move blobs to archive storage" -> specify a value which means after x days, it will move to archive storage:

[image]

**Note**: the rule may [take a few hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#faq) to take effect.

Comment: I don't have "Lifecycle Management" in the "Data Lake Storage" menu, but only "Containers". Do you know why?

Comment: what's your region? there is an issue for "lifecycle management" as of now for some regions.

Comment: West Europe. Where do you see there is an issue?

Comment: A few days before, my colleague who is in US has the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557736/not-able-to-see-lifecycle-management-option-for-adls-gen2?noredirect=1#comment103734821_58557736), but it's good at my side. And He has confirmed with MS, it's a bug. Some regions are currently not using this feature.

Comment: @MagnusJohannesson, if you cannot wait for the fixing, I can write some code for you in the next day:)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that urgent. Hopefully the bug is soon fixed.

Comment: OMG be careful with Lifecycle management. The DEFAULT action when you create a new rule is to 'Delete the blob'!!!!